# Python Protocol Use Static Method or Ellipsis?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python protocol.

```
class FooBar(Protocol):
    @staticmethod
    def some_method(data: Dict[str, Any], conn: Connection) -> BaseModel:
```

And recently I've seen people implement the Protocol methods with an Ellipsis like this.

```
class FooBar(Protocol):
    def some_method(data: Dict[str, Any], conn: Connection) -> BaseModel:
        ...
```

Is there a benefit to using a static method vs an ellipsis within the context of a Protocol?

Comment: The ellipsis doesn't have anything to do with the Protocol using staticmethod or not

Comment: Yes, but I'm curious if there is a preferred or "right" way to implement methods derived in a Protocol. Naturally all the methods are static but should it be denoted with the @staticmethod flag or with the ellipsis for these methods? I've even seen pass used. I think I might be overthinking this lol.

Comment: No, why are you saying that "naturally all methods are static", that isn't true. You only decorate them with `staticmethod` or `classmethod` if that is what you intend for the protocol to match.

Comment: The convention is to use ellipses. See the example in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) which will link you to [PEP544](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/) if you want more details and motivations

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I guess you could use `classmethod` on these so my statement was inaccurate. I'll go with the `...` convention linked in the official docs you provided. Thank you.

Comment: I think you have some sort of idea that they should have `classmethod` or `staticmethod`, but they shouldn't in general, only in the *specific* case that you want a classmethod or a staticmethod